# Android - TimePickerDialog are not themed when using dark theme

Tags: android, kotlin

My material time picker is not themed correctly with dark theme
[here is a screenshot of my timePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHUxb.png)

```
 <!--    Dark theme parent. -->
<style name="DarkThemeParent" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge">
    .
    .
    <!--    Material Time Picker Theme -->
    <item name="materialTimePickerTheme">@style/DarkMaterialTimePickerTheme</item>

</style>

<!--    Dark Time Picker-->
<style name="DarkMaterialTimePickerTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
</style>
```

and this is how i show MaterialTimePicker in my

```
val picker: MaterialTimePicker =
                MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
                    .setHour(morningCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
                    .setMinute(morningCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                    .build()
```

Edit: i noticed that it's working fine based on the system theme but it's not working when the my app's theme is dark and the system theme is light

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker** have you tried using the **Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog.Bridge** as a parent of your DarkMaterialTimePickerTheme?